# module 'odoo.tools.pycompat' has no attribute 'integer_types' odoo 13

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13, isinstance

i have an code related to pycompat library in odoo 12 when i tried to upgrade this code in odoo 13
**it gives me below error:**

```
if isinstance(res_ids, pycompat.integer_types):
AttributeError: module 'odoo.tools.pycompat' has no attribute 'integer_types'
```

**my python code is below:**

```
def generate_email(self, res_ids, fields=None):
    self.ensure_one()
    multi_mode = True
    if isinstance(res_ids, pycompat.integer_types):
        res_ids = [res_ids]
        multi_mode = False
    if fields is None:
        fields = ['subject', 'body_html', 'email_from', 'email_to', 'partner_to', 'email_cc', 'email_bcc', 'reply_to',
                  'scheduled_date']

    res_ids_to_templates = self.get_email_template(res_ids)
```

So, what kind of changes i need to do in this code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`integer_types` was a shim used to maintain compatibility with Python 2 code.  This shim (and others) have been [removed](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/commit/758382b3a73da024d6e1dc04a474d2868223767a) in Odoo 13.

You should compare against `int` directly instead

```py
if isinstance(res_ids, int):
    ...
```

Comment: This will also give below error:
AttributeError: module 'odoo.tools.pycompat' has no attribute 'int'

Comment: It looks like you are doing `isinstance(res_ids, pycompat.int)`.  Use bare `int` as in the answer.